# Fetching key from an array of array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, key

I'm trying to parse this data from this simple array called $mission_data.  12654 and 12777 are keys to a long list of records. As an example i need to put the key 12654 into a variable so I can group them with their UserId's.

```
Array
(
 [12654] => Array
   (
     [UserID] => 294
       )
        [12777] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => 320
        )
     )
```

**My code looks like this:**

```
foreach($mission_data as $data){
$lloc_key = key($mission_data);
$user_ID = $data['UserID'];     
echo 'Location ID ='.$lloc_key."<br>";
echo 'User ID ='.$user_ID;}
```

**The result I get back is:**

```
Location ID =12654
User ID =294

Location ID =12654
User ID =320
```

**If I replace $mission_data in the second line of that foreach loop with $data, I get the below:**

```
Location ID =UserID
User ID =294

Location ID =UserID
User ID =320
```

I can't seem to get the key back from the first level of the array (and have it advance with the foreach loop.  What am I doing wrong?

I know this is 101, but I'm stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($mission_data as $key => $data) {
    $user_ID = $data['UserID'];
    echo 'Location ID =' . $key . "<br>";
    echo 'User ID =' . $user_ID;
}
```

You can use the `$key => $value` of foreach loop to get the key of your array you try to access instantly.

Comment: Thank you for this quick response.  Can I ask, is the $key variable a way to retrieve the key?  Is that just a function within PHP?  I'm not sure I understand how $key retrieves that, unless it's a feature. :)

Comment: It's a feature of `foreach` loop. Your first approach was not so wrong, with small modifications it would work but the way i propose is faster using less code. If i helped you solve your issue please don't forget to accept my answer for future users to see.

Comment: Glad i helped :)